# How to disable specific notification popup? Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kde, notification

I am using '[Google Play Desktop Music Player](https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/Google-Play-Music-Desktop-Player-UNOFFICIAL-)' to play music, and every time the song changes I get a notification popup:

[image]

I would like to disable this notification, however I cannot find anywhere in the app nor in the KDE notification settings where I can do this.

Generically I am finding managing notifications in KDE difficult, as the settings panel for notifications has many categories and no search feature:

[image]

I haven't been able to find further information on managing my notifications in KDE, and I feel like I must be missing something about how to configure them. This has been bothering me for notifications from many different sources.

I am running Kubuntu 18.04.3 with kubuntu backports:
KDE Plasma Version: 5.12.9
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.47.0
Qt Version: 5.9.5

Comment: I installed version 4.7.1 from your link on Kubuntu 1**9.10**. I'm listening to a YouTube playlist but don't see any notification when the next video starts. So maybe things are different on Kubuntu 19.10. In any case, which applications are causing the most problems? Maybe we can look at each one separately.

Comment: I don't remember which ones were bothering me previously, I'll update if I come across another.